# Как вызывать функцию в декораторе

Tags: javascript, функции, шаблоны-проектирования, декоратор

Я до этого писал вопрос о том, как прижать футер к низу страницы, потом решил его, но столкнулся с проблемой, что я не понимаю, как мне вызывать срабатывание функции, после того, как я ужимаю браузер. В итоге я нашёл решение - сделать для функции расчёта футера функцию-декоратор устранения дребезга.
**Описание функции:**
`debounce(fn, wait)` создает вариант функции, которая выполняет *оригинальную* функцию спустя `wait` миллисекунд *после* предыдующего вызова *декорированной* функции. Паттерн также применяется в работе с повторяющимися событиями. Он полезен, если функциональность должна быть выполнена по завершению очереди событий.
Но я столкнулся с проблемой - функция срабатывает через нужное время, но рассчитывает она старые значения, при которых вызывался декоратор(запоминает функцию и выполняет её через время). Я не понимаю, как мне вызвать функцию, чтобы она рассчитала значения только когда вызвалась

**UPD:**
Я всё это время занимался ресайзом и я понял, что `calcFooter()` вызывается только через время. Если я буду ресайзить страницу и 100 мс между ресайзами не пройдёт, то calcfooter не вызовется, т.е. `calcFooter()` вызывается только после 100мс от последнего ресайза. Возможно я просто высчитываю неправильно значения в `calcFooter()`?

```js
let header = document.querySelector('.header');
let footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
let mainContent = document.querySelector('main.content');
let heightFooter;
let heightHeader;
calcFooter();

function calcFooter() {
 heightFooter = footer.offsetHeight;
 heightHeader = header.offsetHeight;
 mainContent.style.height = window.innerHeight - heightFooter - heightHeader + 'px';
}

function debounce(fn, interval) { // функция-декоратор устранения дребезга
    let timer;
    return function debounced() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        let args = arguments;
        let that = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function callOriginalFn() {
             fn.apply(that, args);
        }, interval);
    };
}


let delayProcess = debounce(calcFooter, 100);


window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 delayProcess();
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/*************** 

HEADER

****************/

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbd5e0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.header.off {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.header__container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 22px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: .5s max-width ease-in-out;
}

.header__container.active .header__logo {
  max-width: 0%;
}


/*************** 

HEADER__BURGER

****************/

.header__burger {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 22.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 45px;
  min-height: 36px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: margin-left .7s ease-in-out;
}

.line__burger {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.line__burger:first-child {
  transform: translateY(9px);
}

.line__burger:last-child {
  transform: translateY(-9px);
}

.header__container.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header__container.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
.header__container.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.burger__menu {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(97, 93, 93);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out, padding-right .7s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.burger__menu .container {
  padding: 10px 10px 60px;
  height: auto;
}

.burger__menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.footer__container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer__left {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer__links {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.footer__link:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.footer__copyright {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer__copyright a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transition: ease-in-out .2s border-bottom, ease-in-out .2s color;
}

.footer__copyright a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)
}

.footer__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer__icons {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer__icons .vk {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d2d1cf;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out background-color;
}

.footer__icons .vk path {
  fill: #333333;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out fill;
}

.footer__icons .vk:hover {
  background-color: #4a76a8;
}

.footer__icons .vk:hover path {
  fill: white;
}

@media (max-width: 1130px) {
  .footer__container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .footer__links {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer__link {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .footer__container {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer__link:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .footer__copyright {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .footer__icons {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__burger">
        <div class="line__burger"></div>
        <div class="line__burger"></div>
        <div class="line__burger"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="header__logo">
        Invest Tavern </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="content">
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer__container">
      <div class="footer__left">
        <div class="footer__links">
          <div class="footer__link">Тут ссылка</div>
          <div class="footer__link">А тут ещё</div>
          <div class="footer__link">Тут тоже</div>
          <div class="footer__link">А тут что-то важное</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__copyright">Этот сайт создал <a>Камахин Михаил</a> в 2019 году</div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer__right">
        <div class="footer__title">
          Салам
        </div>
        <div class="footer__text">
          Как дела?<br> А вот мой вк
        </div>
        <div class="footer__icons">
          <a class="vk__link">
            <svg class="vk" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-8 0 50 19" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
       <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M31.5584982,1.28655527 C31.7808894,0.544942969 31.5584984,0 30.500061,0 L27.000061,0 C26.1101263,0 25.6998536,0.470750876 25.4773391,0.989848628 C25.4773391,0.989848628 23.6974695,5.32823432 21.1760494,8.14629935 C20.3603068,8.96204202 19.9894697,9.2215909 19.5445024,9.2215909 C19.3220495,9.2215909 18.9883086,8.96204202 18.9883086,8.22049144 L18.9883086,1.28655527 C18.9883086,0.396620508 18.7417351,0 18.000061,0 L12.500061,0 C11.943929,0 11.6094667,0.413039057 11.6094667,0.804491844 C11.6094667,1.64813371 12.8701151,1.84268735 13.000061,4.21584672 L13.000061,9.36997508 C13.000061,10.5 12.7959847,10.7048772 12.3510173,10.7048772 C11.1644994,10.7048772 8.27829116,6.34711025 6.56650306,1.36068564 C6.23103383,0.391497427 5.89456337,0 5.00006104,0 L1.50006104,0 C0.500061035,0 0.300048828,0.470750876 0.300048828,0.989848628 C0.300048828,1.91687944 1.48662852,6.514814 5.82495248,12.5959115 C8.71714788,16.7488169 12.7920612,19 16.500061,19 C18.7248362,19 19.000061,18.5 19.000061,17.6387517 L19.000061,14.5 C19.000061,13.5 19.2108231,13.3004277 19.9153394,13.3004277 C20.4344371,13.3004277 21.3243719,13.5599766 23.4008863,15.5622989 C25.773984,17.9353966 26.1652206,19 27.500061,19 L31.000061,19 C32.000061,19 32.500061,18.5 32.2116188,17.513278 C31.8959765,16.5298527 30.7629505,15.1030336 29.259531,13.4116541 C28.4437266,12.447589 27.2201126,11.4093935 26.8492755,10.8901723 C26.3301778,10.2228138 26.4785003,9.92610716 26.8492755,9.33287904 C26.8492755,9.33287904 31.1135309,3.32591196 31.5584982,1.28655527 Z"/>
      </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <!-- .footer__icons -->
      </div>
      <!-- .footer__right -->
    </div>
    <!-- .footer__container -->
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</footer>
```

Comment: а почему Вы решили добавить debounce?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я сам не понимаю, пытаюсь просто решить это на js, мне посоветовали debounce и throttling, я подумал, что мне нужно через время это делать в debounce

Comment: я к тому что можно обрабатывать все события, от этого была какая-то проблема?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я не понимаю, что значит все события?

Comment: ну debounce сглаживает, чтобы события реже вызывались, так?

Comment: Посоветовали не debounce и throttling, а ***изучить распространенные паттерны, вместо траты времени на попытку делать в JS то, что делается через CSS***! Это было сказано в контексте цели страданий с задачей, решение которой не даст полезного опыта. Логика: "подобные костыли в норме не используются, а декораторы обработчиков используются => полезнее будет освоить второе, чем первое". В предыдущем вопросе дана ссылка на CSS-решение.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вообще всё плохо понимаю, думаю мне нужно пойти практиковаться в `js` и через время я смогу понять это. Я сейчас пытался написать разницу между троттлингом и debounce в моём понимании, но не смог.

Comment: Для назначения debounced функции обработчиком события, надо передать аргументом ее саму (а не результат ее вызова). В данном случае: `window.addEventListener('resize', delayProcess);` или `window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(calcFooter, 100));`. Хотя и с оборачиванием в еще одну функцию все будет работать (возможно, просто ожидаемый результат не соответствует назначению debounce как приема, его сути?).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// объект с классом body вставляем в переменную body1 для дальнейшей краткости кода
let body1 = document.getElementsByClassName('body');

// размер экрана
let wwww = innerWidth;

// при изменении размера эерана через 3 сек присваивает различные классы
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {

       let inff = function () {
       
       if (wwww <= 304) {
                        body1.classList.add("class1")
                    } else if (wwww <= 500) {
                        body1.classList.add("class2")
                    } else if (wwww <= 767) {
                        body1.classList.add("class3")
                    } else if (wwww <= 991) {
                        body1.classList.add("class4")
                    } else if (wwww <= 1200) {
                        body1.classList.add("class5")
                    } else if (wwww <= 1440) {
                        body1.classList.add("class6")
                    } else if (wwww <= 1600) {
                        body1.classList.add("class7")
                    } else {
                        body1.classList.add("class8")
                    }
                }
        inff();

    }, 3000);
}, false);
```

проверьте непропустил ли я скобочку где-второпях писал,
присваивает разные классы в зависимости от ширины браузера при изменении(решил сжать браузер чтобы заодно смотреть клипы например), да в этих классах добавьте в стилях transition: 1s; для плавности.

это несовсем обертка а чтот подобное media.css но в отличии это при изменении действует а css сразу при открытии браузера.